# Installer Android

Tags: java, android

I need to make an installer which will ask for T&C and install the App . But i am not able to find any tutorial related to the same . 
Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android Market handles the task of installing all programs. The best you will probably be able to do is, at the start of your program, use a dialog to display your T & C and if the user does not agree- quit the program. If they do agree, use the SharedPreferences or a Database to store that so you don't have to ask every time the user opens your app.